# Ajax.BeginForm not working with Html.ValidationSummary

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to use the Ajax.BeginForm to post data to a controller.  In the case of specific errors, the form should re-render and display the custom error message that was added to the ModelState.  For some reason, the error message is not displaying.  I am even trying the following test case which is not working, am I missing something?

```
Edit.cshtml:
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Edit", "UserInformation", FormMethod.Post, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "divFormContainerMain", LoadingElementId = "divPreLoader", OnSuccess = "onSuccess" }))
{
    <div id="divPreLoader" style="display:none; text-align: center"><img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/preLoader.gif")" alt="" /></div>
    <div id="divFormContainerMain">
        @Html.Partial("_EditPartialView", Model)
    </div>
    <div class="buttonContainerBottom">
        <span class="buttonContainerInner">
            <input type="submit" id="btnSave" name="buttonPress" value="save" class="orangeButton" />
        </span>
    </div>
}


_EditPartialView.cshtml:
@Html.ValidationSummary(false)
<div id="divFormContainerUserInformation" class="formContainer">
    <div class="labelContainer">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
    </div>
    <div class="elementContainer">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { style = "width: 200px" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
    </div>
    <div class="labelContainer">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
    </div>
    <div class="elementContainer">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { style = "width: 200px" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)
    </div>
    <div class="labelContainer">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.EmailAddress)
    </div>
    <div class="elementContainer">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EmailAddress, new { style = "width: 200px" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.EmailAddress)
    </div>
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
</div>

UserController:
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(UserModel userModel)
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "This is a test");
    return PartialView("_EditPartialView", userModel);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure that you have included the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` script to your view after jquery itself. Otherwise the Ajax.BeginForm helper won't do what you think it does:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/scripts/jquery-YOUR-VERSION.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")"></script>
```

Comment: Here are the script entries:  <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/kendo.web.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: I can't see `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` being included anywhere. That's why your code probably doesn't work as explained in my answer. Make sure that you have included this script as well.

Comment: Sorry:     <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/kendo.web.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: Your script inclusion now look alright. Is your controller action being hit? What do you see in Firebug? Can you see the AJAX request being sent? what does the server respond to this request?

Comment: In my debugger, I set a breakpoint at the call to the PartialView and I can see the line begin reached.

Answer (score 7):

Where are your scripts added? In the _layout.cshtml or in the view itself? How are you loading the view? Is it with an ajax request to show a partial view?

If you are loading the partial view through ajax or as a partial view, maybe it could be that the partial view was not yet loaded in the jquery DOM model tree.

I would try the following. Change

```
<div id="divFormContainerMain">
    @Html.Partial("_EditPartialView", Model)
</div>
```

to

```
<div id="divFormContainerMain">
    @Html.Partial("_EditPartialView", Model)
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</div>
```

or

```
<div id="divFormContainerMain">
    @Html.Partial("_EditPartialView", Model)
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval") //if you have a bundle for it
</div>
```

My advice is anyway to load the validate and unobtrusive scripts only when you need them and not in the _layout.cshtml page.

Also don't forget to enable the following appSettings in the web.config

```
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

Comment: +1 for the web.config suggestion - that was exactly what I was missing!